# Somar a diagonal de uma matriz (ponteiros)

Tags: ponteiro

Alguém me consegue explicar o que significa "a[i]+i"? Quando i=0 o ponteiro aponta para o 2. Mas quando i=1 não deveria ser a[1]+1 = 4+1 = 5? Na prática aponta para o 8...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int soma;
    int a[2][2] = {{2,4},{6,8}};
    printf("SOMA: %d\n", soma_diag(2, a));
}

int soma_diag(int n, int a[n][n])
{
    int soma=0, i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        soma += *(a[i]+i);
    return soma;
}
```

Comment: `*(a[i]+i)` é uma maneira exótica de dizer `a[i][i]`; `a[1]` não é o 4 mais sim um apontador que aponta para o array `{6,8}`; `a[1]+1` aponta para o 8;  `*(a[1]+1)` é o 8.

Comment: Penso que já percebi, então caso ainda houvesse outra linha na matriz, p.ex {10,12}, *(a[2]+1) apontava para o 10 e *(a[2]+2) apontava para o 12, certo?

Comment: Experimenta. Está quase: `(a[2]+1)` aponta para o 12; `*(a[2]+1)` é o 12  . `*(a[2]+0)` seria o 10.

Comment: Exato, só seria a[2]+2 caso houvesse outra coluna.